# App wide Static Variable C# Console application

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-core

I am looking to use a variable `Config` instantiated in `Program.cs` to be able to use in other classes I have. As I understand, we need to use dependency injection, but not sure how to achieve.

---

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    static IConfigurationRoot Config = null;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
          .AddEnvironmentVariables()
          .Build();
    }
}
```

**TestClass.cs**

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         // Now I need to use that instantiated Config object here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unusual to reference members of an executable assembly in another class. I think you should reconsider the design.

Comment: Can you suggest how that can be done please? My requirement here is to to be able to access all the config entries, anywhere in the app.

Comment: I like to create a configuration respository and treat config data like any data store (like a database). So maybe create a class specifically to hold those fields. You could use that variable if it was public by: `Program.Config`, but it would be a misuse of the Program class in terms of SOLID principles.

Answer (score 3):

You can either make Config `static public`, so it can be accessed anywhere in your application, or, if you want to use Dependency Injection, make your `TestClass` constructor ask for one `IConfigurationRoot`:

```
public TestClass(IConfigurationRoot config) 
{
    // do what you need
    // save a reference to it on a local member, for example
}
```

Now every time you instantiate a new `TestClass`, you will have to pass by argument to its constructor the `IConfigurationRoot` object it will use. If that proves to be troublesome (e.g.: you instantiate `TestClass` a lot, in a lot of different places), then you might use a `TestClassFactory`:

```
public class TestClassFactory
{
    public TestClass Get()
    {
        // Do your logic here to get a new TestClass object
        // The IConfigurationRoot object that will be used to create TestClasses
        // will be chosen here.
    }
}
```

Also, if you don't want to use ASP.NET types directly, you may, as Crowcoder pointed out, make a config repository, as you would do for any database model. That repository would fetch configuration from a json file, for example.

Something like this:

```
public class ConfigurationRepository : IConfigurationRepository
{
    public string GetBasePath()
    {
        // Read base path from config files
    }

    public string SetBasePath()
    {
        // Write base path to config files
    }
}
```

And then you would use DI to pass `IConfigurationRepository` to your `TestClass`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Config` is declared `public static`, then it can be accessed from other classes as `Program.Config`